# How to convert Asp.net mvc 3 mobile web Application to Android Application using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, asp.net-mvc-3, cordova, xamarin.android

I m developing mobile web application using Asp.net mvc 3, jquery mobile, jquery it is running fine in android, iPhone.

How to convert this application into Android application using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

First I do prefer not to convert them. Because if you are directly converting that you can not take benefit of native UI. But it will look same in mobile like it is running in mobile browser. But still if you want to try you can use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) .

If you want to do things with native I highly recommend [mono for android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) . So, your backend will stay in asp.net mvc application and other things move to native application. And you can code in C# only.

Please let me know if any-other information needed.

Comment: Thanks @kunjee I using phonegap for application.I m new to java(Eclipse).I want to develop application in mvc framework in eclipse.Is that possible?

Comment: If you are familiar with C# then develop with it only. That will be better, MVC is just a concept, I don't know more about android framework there. But I do know about mobile C# framework for android development. http://monocross.net/ check out this, that will give you an idea.

Comment: @kanna If your question is solved please select correct answer and close the question. if any more information needed please let me know.

Comment: Last I check it was open source but monodroid is not opensource you have to pay little payment for that. But it is worth paying as it give native access in C# with all the goodness of C#.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23553/discussion-between-kanna-and-kunjee)